# SLComposeServiceViewController refresh configurationItems?

Tags: ios, swift

I followed [this guide](https://www.talkmobiledev.com/2017/01/22/create-a-custom-share-extension-in-swift/) on how to setup a `SLComposeViewController`, and it includes on how to set up configuration items.

I'm pulling from a MongoDB database to get the most recently modified item. Here is my `configurationItems()`:

```
    override func configurationItems() -> [Any]! {
        let configurationItems = [editConfigurationItem]
        
        return configurationItems
    }
```

and here is my `editConfigurationItem` variable:

```
    lazy var editConfigurationItem: SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem = {
        
        func getFirstCategory(completion: @escaping(String) -> ()) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let email: String = customKeychainWrapperInstance.string(forKey: "email") ?? ""
                let password: String = customKeychainWrapperInstance.string(forKey: "password") ?? ""
                
                app.login(credentials: Credentials.emailPassword(email: email, password: password)) { (maybeUser, error) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                        guard error == nil else {
                            print("Login failed: \(error!)");
                            return
                        }
                        
                        guard let _ = maybeUser else {
                            fatalError("Invalid user object?")
                        }
                        print("Login succeeded!");
                    }
                    let user = app.currentUser!
                    let configuration = user.configuration(partitionValue: user.id)
                    let predata = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
                    let unsortedData = predata.objects(Tiktoks.self)
                    let data = unsortedData.sorted(byKeyPath: "date", ascending: false)
                    let firstCategory = data[0].category
                    let firstCategoryId = data[0]._id
                    print(firstCategory)
                    print(firstCategoryId)
                    self.selectedId = firstCategoryId
                    completion(firstCategory)
                }
            }
            print("done")
        }
        
        let item = SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem()!
        item.title = "collection"
        item.valuePending = true
        getFirstCategory() { (firstCategory) in
            item.valuePending = false
            print("completed")
            item.value = firstCategory // Using self as the closure is running in background
        }
        item.tapHandler = self.editConfigurationItemTapped
        return item
    }()
```

(Sorry for the messiness of the code, I'm new to Swift)

So far it works, but the `item.value` variable doesn't get updated in the UI. It "infinitely loads" until you click on the configuration item. When the configuration item is tapped to go to another view though, the actual variable from the database shows for a split second before showing the next view. When you go back from that other view, the actual variable is there.

[image]

It looks like to me that the configuration item isn't updating. I see that there is a [`reloadConfigurationItems()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/social/slcomposeserviceviewcontroller/1623326-reloadconfigurationitems), but by putting that in my `editConfigurationItem` will cause a loop I would think (and it also errors out too). The documentation even says:

> In particular, you don’t need to call this method after you change a configuration item property, because the SLComposeServiceViewController base class automatically detects and responds to such changes.

but it looks like it's not detecting the changes.

Is there a way to refresh `item.value` and `item.valuePending`?